# Table like format through divs and css

Tags: css, html

I have the following css and html code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .formLayout
    {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        border: solid 1px #a1a1a1;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }

    .formLayout label, .formLayout input
    {
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .formLayout label
    {
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    br
    {
        clear: left;
    }
    .box_header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1em;

}
    </style>


   <div class="formLayout"  style="float:left; margin-left: 100px; margin-top:5em;">
            <div class="box_header">
             Install
    </div>
            <label>Type</label>
            <label>Amount</label>
            <label>Days</label>
            <br>
            <input id="type" name="type" size="25">
            <input id="amount" name="amount" size="5">
            <input id="days" name="days" size="5"><br>
        </div>
```

I am trying to create that in table like format so that all the cells are aligned nicely. But for some reason i can't get the labels and input boxes to align correctly. Can someone please help me with this.

an example of what i want it to look like is this:

```
<table align="center">
    <thead>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Days</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>            
        </tr>                                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you consider "correct alignment"? A screenshot or diagram would help.

Comment: I never used that before, how would i convert what i have?

Comment: Do you want it lined up like this? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: Well, 120px for each `<label>` makes 360px…and `formLayout` can only hold 300px. Does this help?

Comment: why not just use tables? This is the purpose they serve. You're not trying to create a layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

**CSS**

```
.formLayout
{
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #f3f3f3; 
}

.ins
{
    margin:auto;
}

.ins
{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
}
.group-div
{
    text-align: center; 
}

.group-div td
{
    width:250px;
}

.group-div input[type="text"]
{
    padding:3px;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class = "formLayout">
    <div class = "ins">
    <center>Install</center>
    </div>

    <div class = "group-div">
    <table>
    <tr><td><label>TYPE</label></td>    
        <td><label>AMOUNT</label></td>
        <td><label>DAYS</label></td></tr>       


    <tr><td><input type = "text"></td>  
        <td><input type = "text"></td>
        <td><input type = "text"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type = "text"></td>  
        <td><input type = "text"></td>
        <td><input type = "text"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type = "text"></td>  
        <td><input type = "text"></td>
        <td><input type = "text"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type = "text"></td>  
        <td><input type = "text"></td>
        <td><input type = "text"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type = "text"></td>  
        <td><input type = "text"></td>
        <td><input type = "text"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

though it seems the codes are very basic hope it helps, still. goodluck! :)

**here's my fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/G4JRU/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for?..

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/pMqkR/

```
   <div class="formLayout"  style="float:left; margin-left: 100px; margin-top:5em;">
        <div class="box_header">
             Install
        </div>
        <label>Type</label><input id="type" name="type" size="25">
        <label>Amount</label><input id="amount" name="amount" size="5">
        <label>Days</label><input id="days" name="days" size="5"><br>
   </div>
```

Comment: exactly like that, but type, amount and days to be on top and then 5 rows of 3 colums of input boxes below that